# Convenção para uso de PouchDB com CouchDB

Tags: pouchdb, couchdb

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples com o pouchDB e couchDB e tenho as dúvidas a seguir:

1. Em um banco normal, relacional (mysql por exemplo) eu teria várias tabelas. A estrutura equivalente no pouch/couch seria criar um banco de dados para cada tabela? Como isso seria feito.
2. Continuando a pergunta acima, supondo que entre estas tabelas do mysql eu tenha relações FK, qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso no pouch/couch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, a comparação entre MySQL e PouchDB é complicada, estamos falando de paradigmas diferentes entre bancos de dados. MySQL é um banco relacional (Entidade/Relacionamento) e PuchDB é não relacional (NoSQL). Umas das principais caracteristicas de um banco de dados NoSQL é ser atômico, já que o mesmo não tem controle transacional.

Mais sobre [NoSQL](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/17043/banco-de-dados/nosql-voce-realmente-sabe-do-que-estamos-falando/)

Tabela comparativa entre os termos:

```
SQL concept     PouchDB concept
table           no equivalent
row             document
column          field
primary key     primary key (_id)
index           view
```

Vamos as suas perguntas:

1) Você teria vários documentos

2) Você teria o relacionamento (PK) no mesmo documento, como por exemplo um array (hobbies):

```
{
 "_id": "mittens",
 "name": "Mittens",
 "occupation": "kitten",
 "age": 3,
 "hobbies": [
   "playing with balls of yarn",
   "chasing laser pointers",
   "lookin' hella cute"
 ]
}
```

Documentação completa do [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html)

Comment: Obrigado, supondo que no mysql eu tenha uma tabela **produtos**, uma **pedidos** e uma de ligação **pedido_produtos**, no *PouchDB* eu criei um **new DB** para cada tabela, isso foge dos conceitos do *PouchDB*, sou novo no assunto, qual seria a melhor maneira de criar esta estrutura no *PouchDB*

Comment: Cria apenas um json pedido e um array de produtos dentro do pedido. A tabela de relacionamento `pedido_produtos` não precisa. Igual ao exemplo acima, entre pessoa e hobby

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, mas no caso do mesmo produto para vários pedidos duplica o produto?

Comment: Sim, repete..este é um dos efeitos colaterais de bancos NoSQL.. isso pode acarretar em falta de sincronia entre produtos iguais.. cabe a você escrever uma aplicação que controle isso. Caso você precise de um banco de dados que preze pela `Normalização` dos dados ao invés de performance/volume de dados.. recomendo utilizar banco de dados relacionais.. como MySQL..

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a sua primeira pergunta: para cada tabela você pode criar um novo documento, o que é muito mais prático que criar um banco para cada tabela.

Quanto a segunda pergunta: banco noSQL (couchDB, por exemplo) não possui fk ou chave primária, mas os relacionamentos 1:1, 1:N e N:N ainda são os mesmos aplicados aos bancos relacionais. Então sua tabela produto, pedido e pedido_produtos ficaria assim no couchDB:

**produto:**

```
    {
     "_id": "100",
     "type": "produto",
     "nome": "mamão",
     "preco": 5.4,
   }
```

**pedido:**

```
    {
     "_id": "200",
     "type": "pedido",
     "data": "12/02/2019",
    }
```

**pedido_produto:**

```
    {
     "_id": "1",
     "type": "pedido_produto",
     "pedido_id": "200",
     "produto_id": "100"
   }
```

E para você conseguir buscar todos esse dados no couchDB de uma única vez,crie uma view no couchDB e coloque esse código:

```
    function (doc) {
      var pedidoID, produtoID;  
      if(doc.type == "pedido_produto"){
       pedidoID = doc.pedido_id;
       produtoID = doc.produto_id;
      }
      if(doc.type == "pedido"){
       emit(pedidoID, {pedido: doc});
      }
     if(doc.type == "produto"){
      emit(produtoID, {produto: doc});
     }
    }
```

Após salvar, para que você possa consumir essa view na sua aplicação, é só fazer uma requisição via ajax, no seu javascript:

```
    function buscarView() {
       $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/nome_do_banco/_design/view/_view/view? 
        include_docs=true',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
          //aqui você manipula o resultado
        },
        error: function (err) {
          var t = err.responseText;
          console.log("Erro de requisição: " + err.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
```